# How to typeset a cumulative frequency curve with non-integer x axis ticks using Tikz and PGF, not pstricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, grids, grid-typesetting, addlines

I am a newbie here. I need your help:

I need to typeset this curve [image: cumulative frequency curve]
using Tikz and pgf only, no pstricks.
The xy values to be plotted are contained in the 3rd  and 4th columns in this table: [image: table]

Note:
I have seen the code in this related example, though I prefer non-integer x ticks:
[How to plot cumulative frequency from a raw data file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460954/how-to-plot-cumulative-frequency-from-a-raw-data-file) 
But this will not be useful for me because I want to avoid pstricks since it's clashing with some codes in my document.

Please I will be very grateful.

Comment: Since there is no closed form solution, you can enter the data from the table and fit a smooth curve,  You can specify the tick values using [xtick={...}] or [xtick=data].

Comment: Thank you. What about the dashed line from 40%? Is there a code that will draw the horizontal dashed line from 40% to meet the smooth red curve and consequently, change course 90° downward and hit the x axis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can let pgfplots accumulate the data, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198397. For the dashed lines one can use intersections. For the percentage one can use the last point of the plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\newcounter{ihor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,
    tick align=outside,tick pos=lower,
    xtick={9,19,...,99},xticklabel=\empty,
    minor tick style={draw=none},x tick style={draw=none},
    extra x ticks={9.5,19.5,...,99.5},
    extra x tick style={draw,grid style={draw=none},x tick style={draw},
        xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick,
        xticklabel style={rotate=30}},
    axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,    
    xmin=9,xmax=100,xlabel=Marks,
    ymin=0,ymax=55,minor tick num=4,ylabel=Cumulative frequency,
    grid=both,grid style={cyan},minor grid style={help lines,cyan},
    table/create on use/cumulative frequency/.style={% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198397
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{frequency}}   
    }]
  \addplot[red,thick,name path global=plot,smooth,mark=+,mark options={color=black}] 
    table [x expr=9.5+10*\coordindex,
      y=cumulative frequency]{
  frequency
  2
  3
  4
  6
  13
  10
  5
  3
  2
  2
  } coordinate[pos=1](pmax);
  \path (0,0) coordinate (O)
    (100,0) coordinate (br) (100,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) coordinate
   (tr); 
  \setcounter{ihor}{0}
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{12.75,25.5,38.25}{%
  \stepcounter{ihor}
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\path[name path=hor-\number\value{ihor}]
   (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#1) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#1);
  \noexpand\draw[dashed,name intersections={of=plot and hor-\number\value{ihor},
    by=i-\number\value{ihor}}] 
    (i-\number\value{ihor}|-O) \ifnum\value{ihor}=1
    node[above left]{$Q_{\arabic{ihor}}$} 
    \else
    node[above right]{$Q_{\arabic{ihor}}$} 
    \fi
        |-  (i-\number\value{ihor}-|O);}
   \temp        
  }
 \path (br) -- (pmax) coordinate[pos=0.4] (p40); 
 \path[name path=hor] (p40) -- (p40-|O);    
 \draw[dashed,name intersections={of=plot and hor,by=i}] 
    (br|-i) -| (br-|i) (i);
\end{axis}
\draw[-stealth] (br) -- (tr);
\path (br) -- (br|-pmax) foreach \X in {0,20,...,100}
 {coordinate[pos=\X/100] (p\X)
 (p\X) edge[help lines]++ (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/minor tick length},0)
 node[pos=\X/100,right,xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/minor tick length}] {\X\%} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: It remains the dotted lines. Q_1, Q_2 and Q_3 mark out 12.75, 25.5 and 38.25 respectively on the left y axis. Is there a code that will enable one to draw the dashed line from say 12.75 on the y axis, the dashed line will meet the curve and automatically drop down and hit the x axis and label the point of contact Q_1, just as in the question? 
In other words, is there a better substitute to the following code for the dashed line Q_1?
\draw [dashed] (8.5,12.75) -- (37.5,12.75) -- (37.5,0) node[] {$Q_1$};

Comment: @ChikaOdiliobi One can use intersections.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate. You are such a gem. I still have 2 questions. Firstly, I tried scaling the whole graph by attaching [scale=1.5] at the back of \begin {tikzpicture}.  Everything scaled, except  the percentage axis. How can I overcome this? Secondly, the fourth line emanating from 40% on the percentage axis. Kindly help me with the code too. Thanks.

Comment: @ChikaOdiliobi One should *never* change the size of a `pgfplots` `axis` by scaling the ambient `tikzpicture`. Rather, use the `width` and `height` keys of the `axis`. I added the dashed line. I also would kindly ask you to ask additional requests in form of new questions.

Comment: Thank you so much.