# How can I draw a graph with squares as in the diagram below

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw a graph with small square boxes
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where's the diagram?

Comment: https://ftp.kddilabs.jp/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Chapter 2.7 of TikZ/PGF Manual (Above) gives you the example of a gridded graph. Gook LuK!

Comment: Hi and welcome. As I understand it, you want the graph to be plotted on graph paper? Is that what you want?

Comment: yes ,but with those small square boxes included

Comment: So you want to do something like https://texample.net/tikz/examples/graph-paper/?

Comment: Thank you so much ,thats exactly what i wanted

Comment: Another solution with PSTricks: [click](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460954/87876).

Answer (score 2):

Since the linked example is only for TiKZ, here is a simple way to add graph paper to any [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) graph.

[image]

This was produced using the following source, compiled with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input graphpaper
beginfig(1);

    path xx, yy, ff;

    xx = 42 left -- 377 right;
    yy = 21 down -- 233 up;


    ff = (20, 20) {right} .. (300, 200) {dir 10};

    drawarrow xx;
    drawarrow yy;

    draw ff withcolor 2/3 red;

    add_background_grid(1cm, 3/4 white);
    add_background_grid(1mm, 7/8 white); 

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The `add_background_grid` macro is defined like this:

```
vardef add_background_grid(expr s, c) = 
    save B, C;
    path B; B = bbox currentpicture;
    picture C; C = currentpicture;
    currentpicture := nullpicture;

    for x = s step s until floor xpart urcorner B:
        draw (x, ceiling ypart llcorner B) -- (x, floor ypart urcorner B) withcolor c;
    endfor
    for x = 0 step -s until ceiling xpart llcorner B:
        draw (x, ceiling ypart llcorner B) -- (x, floor ypart urcorner B) withcolor c;
    endfor
    for y = s step s until floor ypart urcorner B:
        draw (ceiling xpart llcorner B, y) -- (floor xpart urcorner B, y) withcolor c;
    endfor
    for y = 0 step -s until ceiling ypart llcorner B:
        draw (ceiling xpart llcorner B, y) -- (floor xpart urcorner B, y) withcolor c;
    endfor
    draw C;
enddef;
```

which I had saved as `graphpaper.mp` and included using the `input graphpaper` line at the top of the first example.

This works by measuring the size of the bounding box of the current picture; erasing the current picture; drawing a grid (from the origin); and then drawing the saved copy of the original picture back on top.

Comment: Thank you so much